# how to create xsd to validate excel file

Tags: c#, xml, excel, xsd

good morning,
i am in a win application in c# language.
i have to read a excel file (both xls and xlsx) and i would validate it with an xsd file but i wrong something because i get an error:
data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1 
if i use the same xsd with corrispondent xml file this work correctly so shoul be a problem in my excel file or in a code to validate my excel file.
i have use this code:

```
     XmlReaderSettings booksSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
     booksSettings.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",XMLImportUsers.xsd");
     booksSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
     XmlReader books = XmlReader.Create(@"D:\test.xml",booksSettings);

      while (books.Read()) { }
```

my xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="UserSettings">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ID_UTENTE" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="ID_GRUPPO" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

etc etc

Can you help me and post a code example to validate xls /xlsx fine from an xsd?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use OpenXML SDK to open XLSX files? - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK

For XLS you have two options:

1. Convert XLS to XLSX - http://b2xtranslator.sourceforge.net/
2. Open XLS via http://npoi.codeplex.com/.

Comment: i have also tryied with xlsx file but result is the same. it gives me error: data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Comment: Why are you trying to validate against XSD? Why not simply open it and if there are problems report it?